# Is it possible to store multiple objects in the clipboard in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard, copy-paste

Is there a tool in Ubuntu to help copy multiple objects and have the ability to paste any of the items later on?
For example:

```
Select obj1: press Ctrl+C+1
Select obj2: press Ctrl+C+2
Select obj2: press Ctrl+C+2
```

While pasting,

```
press Ctrl+V+1 to paste obj1
press Ctrl+V+3 to paste obj3
press Ctrl+V+2 to paste obj2
press Ctrl+V+1 to paste obj1
...
```